# create application Icon

Tags: android

How to create application Icon for the main Activity?

I want to create a shortcut to customize my application icon on the home screen page.

I want it applied on main screen after application installation.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Welcome to SO!! Please search for existing questions here on SO because there are many QA already exists for the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your icon, put it in drawable folder, then in your manifest...

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: -1 Read question carefully. He want to create app shortcut on home screen.

Comment: hmm I wonder why the downvote? Basically this seem to be the answer

Comment: @PareshMayani maybe I misread the question and my edit changed it?

Answer (score 2):

**Method for adding shortcut**

```
private void addShortcut(){
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

// Shortcut name
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
shortcutIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(this.getPackageName(), "."+this.getLocalClassName());
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setComponent(comp));

// Shortcut icon
ShortcutIconResource iconRes = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon);
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconRes);

sendBroadcast(shortcutIntent);
}
```

**Method for removeing shortcut**

```
private void delShortcut(){
Intent shortcut = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");

// Shortcut adı
shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));

String appClass = this.getPackageName() + "." +this.getLocalClassName();
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(this.getPackageName(), appClass);
shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setComponent(comp));

sendBroadcast(shortcut);
}
```

**Calling methods on OnCreate**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
delShortcut();
addShortcut();
```

**Permissions for adding shortcuts**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```